# Deep merge objects containing functions which returns objects

Tags: javascript

What's a good way of merging multiple objects together which themselves sometimes include functions that return objects?

Here `obj1` and `obj2` are objects with the prop key with the value of a function that returns another object.

`obj3` is a plain object

Is there any way to create a merge function which returns the wanted result?

The problem itself:

```js
const obj1 = {
  prop: (arg) => ({
    val1: arg,
    val2: "word"
  })
}

const obj2 = {
  prop: (arg) => ({
    val3: arg,
    val4: "another word"
  })
}

const obj3 = {
  prop: {
    val5: "hey",
    val6: "forth word"
  }
}

// Wanted Result:
{
  prop: (arg) => ({
    val1: arg,
    val2: "word",
    val3: arg,
    val4: "another word",
    val5: "hey",
    val6: "forth word"
  })
}
```

The real usecase:

```js
import React from "react";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { deepmerge } from "@mui/utils";

const baseTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        contained: ({ theme, ownerState }) => ({
          color: theme.palette.default,
          backgroundColor: theme.palette[ownerState.color].main,
          border: "3px solid",
          borderColor: theme.palette[ownerState.color].main,
          "&:hover": {
            borderColor: theme.palette[ownerState.color].light
          }
        }),
        outlined: ({ theme, ownerState }) => ({
          border: "3px solid",
          borderColor: "grey",
          color: "grey",
          "&:hover": {
            border: "3px solid",
            borderColor: theme.palette[ownerState.color].main,
            color: theme.palette[ownerState.color].main
          }
        }),
        text: ({ theme, ownerState }) => ({
          color: "grey",
          "&:hover": {
            color: theme.palette[ownerState.color].main
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
});

const lightTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        contained: {
          color: "white"
        },
        outlined: {
          color: "black"
        },
        text: {
          color: "black"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

const darkTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        contained: {
          color: "black"
        },
        outlined: {
          color: "white"
        },
        text: {
          color: "white"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

const theme = createTheme(deepmerge(baseTheme, lightTheme));

export default function ThemeNesting() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button color="primary" variant="contained">
        Primary
      </Button>
      <Button color="secondary" variant="contained">
        Secondary
      </Button>
      <Button color="primary" variant="outlined">
        Primary
      </Button>
      <Button color="secondary" variant="outlined">
        Secondary
      </Button>
      <Button color="primary" variant="text">
        Primary
      </Button>
      <Button color="secondary" variant="text">
        Secondary
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/theme-merge-problem-ep4mi?file=/demo.js

Currently the objects in lightTheme gets used over the ones in baseTheme instead of extending it.

Comment: Would you please show us what you have tried till now?

Comment: I've answered and deleted it twice now because I'm not sure your contrived example really demonstrates what your need truly is. Can you provide a real world use case that more clearly demonstrates your end result?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I have added the real usecase to the post

Comment: Great. So in the `baseTheme` object `contained`, `outline` & `text` have functions as values. Yet in the theme you want to merge, those three properties have objects as values. How do you intend to reconcile that in code? You can certainly merge different values types, but it won't go well.

Comment: Additionally, that code should be in this question so everyone has a chance to help.

Comment: @RandyCasburn my plan was to merge so if any of the themes have function as value it will merge the lighttheme's values into the return statement of the function. As shown above.

Comment: "_...into the return statement of the function_" - is just a very, vary bad thing to do. You should rethink this so that your base theme is a simple object structure that is modified - not function definitions. This way each function can return an object that is very simply merged.

Comment: @RandyCasburn problem is that i need the dynamic values of the theme and ownerState. unless i wanna manually write theme for every color i wanna use and variant. and then for every component i wanna theme.

Comment: Would it be out of the question to pass in whatever theme overrides you need as an argument when creating `baseTheme`? e.g. `const theme = overrides => createTheme({ /* ... */ })`. In other words, injecting the light or dark theme instead of merging it to a base theme. Then you'd have access to whatever specific overrides when creating the theme, right? Granted, I'm not familiar with the MUI `createTheme`, so take this as a question rather than a recommendation.

Comment: @natancodes sadly that wouldn't give me access to the color prop nor the theme.
theme and ownerState gets assigned for each component that renders individually via createTheme

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this. You can change it to fit into your theme usecase. You can also use a for loop instead of reduce

```
const obj1 = {
  prop: arg => ({
    val1: arg,
    val2: 'word',
  }),
};

const obj2 = {
  prop: arg => ({
    val3: arg,
    val4: 'another word',
  }),
};

const obj3 = {
  prop: {
    val5: 'hey',
    val6: 'forth word',
  },
};



const merge = (...items) => ({
  prop: arg => {
    return items.reduce((allItems, currentItem) => {
      if (typeof currentItem.prop === 'function') {
        return { ...allItems, ...currentItem.prop(arg) };
      }

      return { ...allItems, ...currentItem.prop };
    }, {});
  },
});

console.log(merge(obj1, obj2, obj3).prop('Yo'));
```